# Is there any way to get Documentum to use Character based Storage for Unicode

Tags: database, unicode, documentum

Anyone out there with sufficient knowledge of EMC Documentum and Oracle to know whether it is possible to set up a documentum repository on top of oracle so that it uses Character based field lengths rather than byte based.

By Default Documentum seems to use byte based fields so if a field is string(32) it can contain 32 bytes rather than characters.  In this instance a set of unicode characters consisting of 32 characters would be truncated since they are more than 32 bytes.

Does anyone know if it is possible through setup of the Oracle and Documentum settings to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. I've done lots of research on this as we got several problems after migrating a docbase from 5.2.5 to 5.3 and a couple of queries stopped working and we we're getting truncation errors in webtop as we we're using an unsupported charset.